# Socket IO broadcast to each client with their socket id

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I'm getting comfortable with socket.io. It really rocks.

I am aware that from the server, I can either:

Respond to a `socket` client:

```
socket.emit(event, data);
```

Broadcast to other clients:

```
socket.broadcast.emit(event, data);
```

Broadcast to all clients without distinction:

```
io.emit(event, data);
```

But what I'd like to do is to loop over the clients to `emit` to each of them, with their `socket.id` as a parameter:

```
io.emitEach(socket => socket.emit(event, dataWichDependsOn(socket.id)));
```

Can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
  io.of('/').clients((error, clients) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    return clients.forEach(clientId => {
      io.to(clientId).emit(event, dataWichDependsOn(clientId));
    })
  }
```

Without success :( the message doesn't seem to be `emit`ed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((clientId)=>{
        io.to(clientId).emit(event, dataWichDependsOn(clientId))
    })
```

Comment: As for me, it's not the `io.of('/').clients()` parts which is not working but the `io.to(clientId).emit()` which doesn't emits... Any hints on that? I'm using `"socket.io": "^2.3.0"`.

Comment: It's all working for me...there is something missing in the code you're providing probably.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25723295)